# Spreading out Code in huge onRendered Callbacks

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm combining PhaserJS with MeteorJS, and I'm worried that I'm going to have MASSIVE amounts of code in an `onRendered` callback.

I'd like to split the many functions across several different files, for simplicity and organization.

Yet, I need to avoid losing scope. How can one divide up a huge `onRendered` function into dozens of smaller files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global object. To avoid problems with the [load order](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp), you always check if the global object already exists at the beginning of a file.

*`client/myHugeObject/somePart`*

```
myHugeObject = myHugeObject || {}

myHugeObject.somePart = function () {}
```

Then in your `onRendered` hook you can simply do:

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function () {
  myHugeObject.somePart()
})
```